# How to install Pulse Secure on Fedora 28

Tags: fedora, vpn, webkit

I have been trying to install Pulse Secure 5.3r4.2-b639 in Fedora 28. I was able to install its dependencies thanks to all the community posting workarounds. There were some dependencies which were not in 28 release like `webkitgtk` but since Pulse Secure uses it I downloaded the F26 one.

Till now I am not able to launch the pulseUi. Right now I'm stuck when running pulseUi and getting error:

```
/usr/local/pulse/pulseUi: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_gl_surface_get_width
```

I have found a couple of posts saying this issue was resolved and it was with webkitgtk 4.2.3 release but I have 4.2.11, the last one before being deprecated.

I can't seem to figure which additional libraries or files I need to go forward.

**NOTE:** I really need this fix as I'll be using F28 as my work OS and need VPN connectivity for various reasons.

Comment: Put a comment whenever you downvote a question so that the OP would know what went wrong. It seems only an edit was made and downvoted for no reason

Comment: Have you tried this approach: https://community.pulsesecure.net/t5/Pulse-Desktop-Clients/Fedora-28-webkitgtk-xulrunner-mozjs17-problem/m-p/38444#M520

Comment: Yes, actually this is one of the resource I often got when searching for the errors and missing deps, but this hidden dependency does not seem to solve the issue for pulse ui and I need it as I have vpn connection through RSA token verification process, so can't use CLI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Fedora 28

I am actually able to use the built in VPN client - Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN(openconnect) - from Desktop GUI inlieu of pulse Secure client.

Have you given it a try?

Open : Settings -> Network -> VPN -> Add VPN -> Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN(openconnect) ->  make sure in VPN Protocol, you select Juniper/Pulse Network Connect.

Comment: great! I don't think I have enough information to connect it from there but I'll see if I can

Comment: Interesting. Does this also work with 2fa?

Comment: it does for me, you'll be asked for input from token

Comment: Works fine for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely *need* to use Fedora? If you are not allergic to Debian/*buntu, you can install the Pulse Secure client in Debian 9 like this:

```
# Install the package
dpkg -i /path/to/ps-pulse-linux-5.3r<version>-ubuntu-debian-64-bit-installer.deb
# Install missing dependencies
apt-get install libproxy1-plugin-gsettings && apt-get install libproxy1-plugin-webkit
```

And that's it. I use the Pulse Secure client daily from my Debian Stretch workstation.

Otherwise, you can utilize this GNUCash-hack:
https://community.pulsesecure.net/t5/Pulse-Desktop-Clients/Fedora-27-webkitgtk-no-longer-supported/m-p/37592#M396

Comment: this solution would be my last resort as I decided when I found this one. Actually I like fedora more than *buntu, but thanks for suggestion

Comment: I did followed the link you gave and it did worked to bring up the pulse ui but then *the last thing I could not even think of* happened. The VPN server does not seem to support linux and it seems I would need to go back to the **Microsoft** world. Alas I really like linux though

Comment: Umm... but are you connecting to a Pulse Secure appliance? I know for a fact that it works with GNU/Linux.

Comment: yes but I am using it to connect to a different server which uses RSA token method for connecting

Comment: okay, there was another URL for macOS but I tried it and it ran for linux as well, so hurray, don't have to go back *there* and thanks for help

Comment: No problem. Glad you're up and running!

Comment: @maulinglawns could you help me? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551977/debian-gnu-linux-9-5-pulse-secure-vpn-ui-host-checker-stuck

Comment: @Black.Jack Sorry, but I no longer need to use this proprietary software. Hopefully someone else can help you out.